# May CrystalDiskInfo SMART values be manipulated? smartctrl shows other values

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, smart

34865 is the value of smartctl and CrystalDiskInfo shows some 2300 hours.

Does it mean SMART values were manipulated?

[image]

```
    C:\Windows\system32>smartctl -a /dev/sda
    smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win7-sp1] (sf-7.0-1)
    Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Model Family:     Hitachi Ultrastar 7K3000
    Device Model:     Hitachi HUA723030ALA641
    Serial Number:    ******
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 225d66d1d
    Firmware Version: MKAOA840
    User Capacity:    3 000 592 982 016 bytes [3,00 TB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
    Form Factor:      3.5 inches
    Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
    ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
    SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Tue Apr 23 11:03:46 2019
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed

                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (29509) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off supp
ort.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 492) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_
FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -
       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   120   120   024    Pre-fail  Always       -
       643 (Average 639)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       362
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -
       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       2324
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       362
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       408
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       408
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   133   133   000    Old_age   Always       -
       45 (Min/Max 15/58)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 8 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 80 00 18 0e 00  Error: UNC 128 sectors at LBA = 0x000e1800 = 923648

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 00 18 0e 40 00      00:08:49.876  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 17 0e 40 00      00:08:49.875  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 17 0e 40 00      00:08:49.875  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 16 0e 40 00      00:08:49.875  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 16 0e 40 00      00:08:49.874  READ DMA EXT

Error 7 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 5b 25 0e 0e 00  Error: UNC 91 sectors at LBA = 0x000e0e25 = 921125

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 00 0e 0e 40 00      00:08:46.977  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 0d 0e 40 00      00:08:46.977  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 0d 0e 40 00      00:08:46.976  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 0c 0e 40 00      00:08:46.976  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 0c 0e 40 00      00:08:46.975  READ DMA EXT

Error 6 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 36 4a 04 0e 00  Error: UNC 54 sectors at LBA = 0x000e044a = 918602

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 00 04 0e 40 00      00:08:44.012  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 03 0e 40 00      00:08:44.012  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 03 0e 40 00      00:08:44.011  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 02 0e 40 00      00:08:44.011  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 02 0e 40 00      00:08:44.011  READ DMA EXT

Error 5 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 10 70 fa 0d 00  Error: UNC 16 sectors at LBA = 0x000dfa70 = 916080

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 00 fa 0d 40 00      00:08:41.006  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 f9 0d 40 00      00:08:41.006  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 f9 0d 40 00      00:08:41.005  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 f8 0d 40 00      00:08:41.005  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 f8 0d 40 00      00:08:41.005  READ DMA EXT

Error 4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 6b 95 f0 0d 00  Error: UNC 107 sectors at LBA = 0x000df095 = 913557

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 80 80 f0 0d 40 00      00:08:38.091  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 f0 0d 40 00      00:08:38.091  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 ef 0d 40 00      00:08:38.091  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 00 ef 0d 40 00      00:08:38.090  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 80 80 ee 0d 40 00      00:08:38.090  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA
_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2315         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2306         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2300         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        14         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       50%     34866         878
016
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     34690         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33691         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26299         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     19849         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         4         -
1 of 1 failed self-tests are outdated by newer successful extended offline self-
test # 1

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of [What does it mean when my new HDD reports errors at a time that shouldn't exist?](https://superuser.com/q/1389522/83694) because the symptoms are exactly the same as in that question.

Answer (score 2):

`Power_On_Hours` is 2324 in smartctl and 2325 in CrystalDiskInfo. Looks okay to me.

```
 9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       2324
```

Values 34865 refer to multiple errors like column `LifeTime(hours)` in Self-test log:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA
_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2315         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2306         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2300         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        14         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       50%     34866         878
016
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     34690         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33691         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26299         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     19849         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         4         -
1 of 1 failed self-tests are outdated by newer successful extended offline self-
test # 1
```

Comment: Thanks. And how all the information like this can be interpreted: "..occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 34865 hours (1452 days + 17 hours).."?

Comment: You had several uncorrectable read errors while powering up the drive. The selftest log shows that a "Short offline" test was run @lifetime 34866 hours with read error, so the test was run while the errors occured or shortly after. But since there are no SMART errors at all (zero errors), I wouldn't worry at this point. The last offline tests also completed without errors. But I can't tell you what caused the problem...

Comment: If someone (theoretically) reset SMART values on HDD. Is there a way to find it out? This case CrystalDiskInfo and smartctl both will show "good"?

Comment: My question is cause I have bought this HDD on April 2018. It was sold as new. So it has to be some 365 days, but not 1450.

Comment: Related: [Hitachi disks at least some of them store power-on lifetime in minutes, rather than hours](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#Iseesomestrangeoutputfromsmartctl.Whatdoesitmean)

Comment: we have a discussion https://superuser.com/questions/1389522/what-does-it-mean-when-my-new-hdd-reports-errors-at-a-time-that-shouldnt-exist/1389525?noredirect=1#comment2156835_1389525

Comment: This drive was certainly manipulated. Power_On_Hours in the SMART record should always be larger the previous log records. The drive's SMART was reset at 34866 hours to conceal read error. This is how they do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ua28W71gFw Resetting SMART Self-test log may be more difficult and few people check the log, but it helps to identify issues.